# Azure AD, Field Engineer Sample, Azure Mobile Service failure to authorize on https://dugisapp2.azure-mobile.net/api/getFieldAgentDisplayName

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

I am modifying the Field Engineer Sample Mobile App to use the data I have in Azure SQL Server.

I can access all my data via Postman, but when I try to start the application to find the errors to finishing the UI development I can't get past AAD Mobile Service authentication.

I see simular unanswered questions. Here are my specifics.

```
Azure Mobile Service Error in its Log
Exception=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException: sts_token_request_failed: Token request to security token service failed. Check InnerException for more details ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.

Postman return from https://xxxxxapp2.azure-mobile.net/api/getFieldAgentDisplayName
{
  "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}

Visual Studio 2013 error.
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 20:16:31 GMT
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=da2b3f6baacfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc5b604b7b9a3d4dbaf9af18;Path=/;Domain=dugisapp2.azure-mobile.net
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 36
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: 0
}}

Error Detail copied from Visual Studio 2013
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException was caught
  _HResult=-2146233079
  _message=The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)
  HResult=-2146233079
  IsTransient=false
  Message=The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)
  Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.<InternalInvokeApiAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.<InvokeApiAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at AzureMobile.Samples.FieldEngineer.Utilities.LoginHelper.<MobileServiceAuthenticate>d__0.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What version packages are you using?  There are two versions of Azure Mobile - "Mobile Services" have a domain azure-mobile.net and are v1 capabiltiies - they need the v1.x libraries.  Azure App Service Mpobile Apps have a domain azurewebsites.net and are v2 capabilities - they need the v2.x libraries.  You can't mix and match.

Comment: We strongly encourage you to use the new version of the product, Mobile Apps, rather than Mobile Services. Here is a simpler version of the sample that uses Mobile Apps that you can deploy to your own subscription with one click: [Azure App Service field engineer sample with web admin portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-fieldengineer/)

Comment: At any rate, the exception shows you haven't set up the AAD client secret correctly. See [Register your apps to use an Azure Active Directory Account login](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/) for more information.